# Thingworx: Get gauge state using REST API

Tags: thingworx

I created simple [mashup](http://learningexchange.ptc.com/tutorial/4733/creating-a-mashup):

[image: gauge]

I would like to get the state of the gauge at the picture using REST GET request. Could you, please, show me the pattern of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could send a GET request with the correct headers (app key, content type and accept) to:

http:///Thingworx/Things/_HTTP_REST_Thing/Properties/nameOfProperty

here is the REST cheat sheet:
https://developer.thingworx.com/resources/guides/thingworx-rest-api-core-concepts/rest-design